# better join for query performance

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I need to select some date from multiple table in oracle. I have 2 tables, **Table A** and **Table B** which should be joined eachother. Let me describe it in table.

**Table A**

```
A_id    x_id    y_id   z_id    price ....
```

**Table B**

```
B_id    xyz_id    myValue
```

NOT : x_id, y_id and z_id keeps same value with (Table B).xyz_id

my query should return

```
A_id, x_id,   y_id,   z_id,  myValue for x_id, myValue for y_id, myValue for z_id
```

I manage that query like

```
select 
    A_id, 
    (select myValue as valueForX_id from TableB where xyz_id = x_id)
    (select myValue as valueForY_id from TableB where xyz_id = y_id)..,
from TableA;
```

but I don't know this will give best performance. I ask for your advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get the values using joins.  I think you will find this performs much faster for large datasets.

```
select a.A_id, a.x_id, a.y_id, a.z_id, x.myValue as x_value,yb.myValue as y_value, z.myValue as z_value
from TableA a
join TableB x on x.xyz_id = a.x_id
join TableB y on y.xyz_id = a.y_id
join TableB z on z.xyz_id = a.z_id
```